# How did the World Government know about the clash between Revolutionary Army and Blackbeard Pirates?

Tags: one-piece

As the recent manga release of One Piece, we all know that Jesus Burgess infiltrated the Revolutionary Army HQ (Baltigo) and reported it to his Captain BB.

My question is how did the World Government know that the Blackbeard Pirates were planning on attacking the Revolutionary Army HQ. we could take note that the one who attack in Baltigo are Cipher Pol, not the Marines.

As I remember, Cipher Pol is directly serving World Government (Nobles). Even if that Information came from marines first. How did they know? Is Aokiji a spy?

Comment: It's way too soon to answer that question, especially now because this chapter came out just yesterday. So I think it's best to close this question.

Comment: @pap non the less it is a valid question. All though the answer might not be available to us right now, it most certainly will be in the future.

Comment: @Dimitrimx You might be right, but still it can be reopened in the near future, when we will have an answer :)

Comment: I just read the chapter again, and it doesn't seem to mention that the World Goverment knew that the Blackbeard Pirates would attack the Revolutionaries. All we know is that they recieved intel from an unknown source which led them to Baltigo, though by the time the Marines and Cipher Pol arrived, the Revolutionaries' HQ was already in ruins, and the Blackbeard Pirates fled as soon as they saw the Marines. Either way, it's still way too early to answer that question ATM.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of one possible solution. The black den den mushi which can spy on people's conversations. I'm guessing that the world government (CP0 or the Marines) were either near Blackbeard or near Baltigo originally spying on either Blackbeard or Baltigo (since it is a suspicious country). Once they tapped into the conversation, they got confirmation of Dragon's location.

The other assumption is that CP0 followed Sabo from Dressrosa to Baltigo. After following them and finding their hideout they planned a full out attack but got there to meet the place in ruins due to the Blackbeard pirates. I doubt that they followed Sabo since the Revolutionary army were secretive and careful about everything they did.

Comment: I think your second assumption is impossible because Burgess woke up on Baltigo after accidentally travelling with Sabo, Koala and Hack after the Dressrosa arc ended. The Blackbeard pirates did not attack Baltigo until they heard from Burgess. So if CP0 followed Sabo and Co. to Baltigo, they wouldn't have found it in ruin because Burgess would still be knocked out or the Blackbeard Pirates didn't arrive yet.

Comment: A more concrete theory would've been better